# MUI TextField Background Color for auto complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an app built with React.js and Material UI, and have issue with the background color for auto-complete fields.

[image]

It adds white background which isn't necessary.

But when I add text manually, this doesn't happen:

[image]

```
<TextField type={props.type ? props.type : 'text'} sx={{ color: '#fff' }} value={props.value} onChange={(e) => props.changeEvent(e.target.value)} label={<Typography variant="body2" sx={{ color: '#fff' }}>{props.placeholder}</Typography>} borderColor="white" fullWidth />
```

This is the component I'm using now.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify why do you name fields as auto-complete but use TextField component. How is value set to "Participant Email" to cause this styles? Could you attach screen shot of this component in DOM to see what classes it has?

Comment: Hi @AnastasiyaStanevich Thanks for your reply, here's the screenshot https://i.imgur.com/ijMxXlW.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is not with Material styles it's browser autofill behaviour. You should override browser's autofill styles.

Here there's one pitfall: color which is set as background for autofill set with `box-shadow` NOT `background-color`, that's why you can't use `transparent` to override. But you can use you background color (here you blue  background `#307ECC`).

Here is css for reset:

```
 input:-webkit-autofill,
 input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
 input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
 input:-webkit-autofill:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #307ECC inset !important;
 }
```

or you can use mui class for it (instead if common `input` tag) `.MuiInputBase-input`.

As well you can override text color for autofill to white using `-webkit-text-fill-color` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following style:

```
   sx={{
            '& .Mui-focused.MuiAutocomplete-input': {
                color: "blue"
            },
        }}
```

You need to override mui style to achieve your goal, so if the above code won't work, try to experiment and see what mui class or combination of classes is responsible for adding the background color on autocomplete.